# Adding Image Reference as a Heading in a Document Outline in a Google Doc

Tags: google-docs

I have a large document in Google Docs that is using images as a headers to some of the sections of the document. I am making sure to use 'heading' text to make sure that the document outline is populating correctly to make it as easy as possible to navigate the document.

You can see on the left side, that there is 'Overview', 'Pricing', 'Use Cases / Examples'.

[image]

In the main document, I'm doing an overview of Slack and I am using the image as a heading. I would love to be able to have that show up in the Document Outline as a heading. I tried to add Alt Text to the image thinking maybe that would be picked up, but it doesn't appear to work.

Is there any way to title an image and have that show up as a heading in the Document Outline of a Google Doc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Google Documents Outline is limited only to text. Alternative solution is to change the font size of the heading and hide it by changing the foreground color to white.

**Example:**

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Yes, I just put the text after the image and made the foreground color white. That's a perfect workaround. Thanks for the clarity on this!